# Delete duplicate points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, duplication

How to delete duplicate points in QGIS (3.14)?

I insert a layer into the project. The layer contains several objects (61 points), some of which are duplicates. In the menu I select `"Vector" > "Check Geometries..."`.

Here I set up to find duplicate points and work with the source layer. It finds duplicates - 26 points. I'll pick them out and set them to be removed.

The dialogue will confirm this to me. But they are not deleted in the source layer, and the layer still has 61 points.

Where am I making a mistake?

[image: Screen1.png]
[image: Screen2.png]
[image: Screen3.png]
[image: Screen4.png]
[image: Screen5.png]
[image: Screen6.png]
[image: Screen7.png]
[image: Screen8.png]

Comment: looks like you need to be in editing mode so you can complete this function.

Comment: i try - it but "...is not allowed to be in editing mode" [link](https://imgur.com/ZGXshTw)

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you to use, `delete duplicate geometries`, you will find this process, in the `process toolbox`, in the `General Vector` options.

If, for some reason fail, you have a similar process in `SAGA`, in `Vector Points Tools,` `remove duplicate points`.